# 'A Facade root has not been set' when running `composer install` after a fresh checkout

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I've recently got a new PC and started to migrate the development of my project over to it. I've installed `php`, `composer` and `git` and checked it out. I run `composer install`, which pulls in all of the dependencies but then throws the following error:

```
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set. in /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(61): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('environment', Array)
#1 /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(353): App\Exceptions\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#2 /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(132): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#3 /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/artisan(33): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
# in /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 234

Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 255
```

I've tried to delete the `vendor` directory and the `composer.lock` file and then re-run `composer install`, but I get the same error. It runs fine on my old machine. Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Have you tried one of the solutions that already exist for the same error? Such as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43850011/1457270)?

Comment: That (and the answers that I've been looking at) relate to changes to the code. I'm convinced that this is an infrastructure problem because it runs absolutely fine when running the same process on a different machine.

Comment: Is Laravel the same version as the one you have on the old machine?

Comment: Yes, Laravel is pulled in when I run `composer install`. The `composer.json` files are identical (they're from the same git repository).

Comment: And you have also run composer install on the old machine today right? So... exactly the same... Can you try php artisan config:cache
 php artisan config:clear
 php artisan cache:clear
 composer update

Comment: Correct. I've just checked out a fresh copy and followed my workflow to the letter on the old machine and it works fine. Running any `php artisan` command results in the above error. If you look at the last line, it's actually `php artisan package:discover` that's causing the error.

Comment: Could something to do with php version i.e. if laravel versions in old and new are the same, guess now the problem is php

Comment: Potentially. I'm having a look through the logs now and I'm getting a `[2019-05-08 20:41:06] laravel.ERROR: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE' {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE' at /home/user/PhpstormProjects/project/config/database.php:60)
[stacktrace]` error. The `database.php` config file is calling `\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true` on the line in question. I'm assuming it could be something to do with that.

Comment: Good update -- I was going to comment that it looks like the Facade Root error is happening by using the `App` facade in your error handler. Definitely looks like an issue with PHP and its extension(s), possibly a missing PDO driver.

Comment: Good shout. `php7.3-mysql` was missing. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After scouring the logs, it turns out that this was down to a missing `php7.3-mysql` driver. Running `sudo apt-get install php7.3-mysql` solved the problem!