# What is the difference between PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase and Tests\TestCase?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

I noticed that in the Example Tests, the two classes are built in.

**Feature Test** => `use Tests\TestCase;`

**Unit Test** => `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;`

What are the differences between the both? In which cases do you use one or the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between unit, functional, acceptance, and integration tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904096/whats-the-difference-between-unit-functional-acceptance-and-integration-test) see also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23392/implementing-the-test-pyramid-as-qa/23396#23396

Comment: Possibly more important than the naming classifications is what they actually do differently. `Tests\TestCase` bootstraps the Laravel application just like it does when you actually use the app. This means you can use the service container for DI, make HTTP requests, or any other thing that depends on Laravel itself. The PHPUnit test case only provides testing helpers, nothing related to Laravel.

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks! That already helps me. So I can also mix both?

Comment: I'm not 100% what you mean by mix both, but the Laravel TestCase will ultimately extend the PHPUnit one.

Comment: Ok. I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`

This is the standard out-of-the-box parent for PHPUnit tests. It only has the functionality provided by PHPUnit.

It is best used when you want "true" unit tests that have no knowledge or scaffolding of Laravel. They are also much faster.

#### `Tests\TestCase`

This is a parent class for many kinds of tests (can be unit, integration, or feature) that **depend on the Laravel app** to function. These scenarios might include:

- Using Eloquent factories to create models
- Using Facades and their fakes
- Unit testing components that use global helpers (e.g. `config()`)
- Using database transactions and/or resets for each test
- Using any of the other augmented functionality and assertions offered by Laravel

`PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` is the parent of `Tests\TestCase`, so all of PHPUnit's standard functionality is also available.

**You can use both!** I use PHPUnit's TestCase when possible for unit tests, and Laravel's for integration and feature testing.

Comment: thank you for the small but good overview.